# Do any Harry Potter characters turn from good to evil?

Tags: harry-potter, good-against-evil

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115803/are-any-harry-potter-characters-completely-redeemed), I'm wondering if there are any instances of characters turning from good to evil in the Harry Potter universe.

There are a few people who turn from bad to good (such as Snape, Karkaroff, Regulus Black etc.), but I can't think of any instances of going in the other direction.

I'm not looking for a complete turnaround as in the linked question, as I doubt there are many instances of a 180 flip (although bonus points if there are), but preferably an example of someone who entirely went from good to evil without being under the effects of the Imperius curse.

For example were there any members of the Order of the Phoenix who defected, or maybe students who were part of Dumbledore's Army who ended up siding with Voldemort (i.e. people who actively worked against Voldemort or other evil forces, and ended up joining them or becoming evil themselves).

---

A good example would be Peter Pettigrew, however even though he was part of the Order it is never really stated in the books that he was ever "good", more that he just followed his friends, and ended up betraying them out of fear as opposed to evil. I'm thinking more of a Lupin or Kingsley type character who ended up becoming bad.

Sirius would have been a prime example, if the events that everyone believed had transpired at the beginning of Prisoner of Azkaban had been true (i.e. being an upstanding Order member, then becoming Voldemort's supporter and betraying Harry's parents).

Comment: luna's father Xenophilius Lovegood? He did not join Voldy, but betray Harry.

Comment: @j4rey89 that is a very interesting answer, exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: [Peter "Wormtail" Pettigrew](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Pettigrew)

Comment: @j4rey89 I'd upvote that if you post as an answer.

Comment: Stan Shunpike.  .

Comment: Wasn't Stan Shunpike under the Imperius Curse??

Comment: Does anyone really *start* evil?  I mean, even Voldemort was probably fine when he was a baby...

Comment: All characters started off good.

Comment: Mundungus ? He went from member of the Order to completely chaotic (rather than evil) but still.

Comment: Cornelius Fudge?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I don't know.   How old was he when he was torturing the other orphans?

Comment: It has to be said that part of the point of the (later) HP novels are that Good and Evil are sometimes not as clear cut as we like to think. People don't have a switch which can be turned from 'good' to 'evil', or the other way. If you are looking to classify people like that you have missed part of the point.

Comment: Umbridge went from bad to worse

Comment: @j4rey89: I wouldn’t say Xenophilius Lovegood turned evil. He was blackmailed, and his priority was to save his daughter.

Comment: 10K views in 4 days! Congratulations.

Comment: Not sure I'm with you on Peter Pettigrew. I feel like if a character did turn from good to evil, the implication would pretty much automatically be that he/she was never truly good. I think Pettigrew works as well as is possible here.

Comment: The only person i can think of close to that, is Luna's father, but still it was just that moment, he called the Death-Eaters because he was desperate not because he was turned into Evil...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman voldy's dad was under love potion, would that by anymeans make him start bad, or has no effect?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You have a lot of good examples here, but I'll add one: **Professor Quirrell**.

> A foolish young man I was then, full of ridiculous ideas about good and evil. My master showed me how wrong I was. There is no good and evil... there is only power, and those too weak to understand it...

More so than the other answers you're getting of people who switched sides out of cowardice (like Pettigrew), Quirrell seems to have gone from a good person who taught Muggle Studies and Defense Against the Dark Arts to someone who fully embraced Voldemort's ideology.

Comment: How much of that was Voldemort sharing his skull and constantly whispering in his ear? I'm sure my personally would alter radically if that were to happen to me.

Comment: @Xantec He did develop his interest in the Dark Arts before he ever met Voldemort, and he was well on his way to becoming a nasty piece of work by then. But his time with Voldy definitely sent him over the edge. His [Pottermore article](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-quirrell) describes it in a bit more detail.

Comment: Then I'll have to include Ginny as well, as a mild case of Quirrell-itis.

Answer (score 168):

If we're willing to accept going from good to doing bad things as being *partially evil*, then there's an obvious answer no one's mentioned:
**Harry Potter.**

Harry does a number of morally questionable things in *Deathly Hallows*. Many of them can be written off as desperate times calling for desperate measures, such as Imperiusing Gringotts staff. However, he also chooses to Cruciatus Amycus Carrow--not because of situational necessity, but in retaliation for his disrespect of Professor McGonagall. There are no exigent circumstances requiring this act. Harry is merely angry and wants to cause pain to someone he considers a justified target.

And we know--from Bellatrix Lestrange's words in *Order of the Phoenix*--that this simply wouldn't work, absent the actual desire to cause pain for its own sake:

> "You need to *mean* them, Potter. You need to really want to cause pain — to enjoy it"

I think it's pretty clear that focused sadism directed at someone you've never even met before counts as an evil step. Sure, Carrow deserves punishment, he's done horrible things; but this little moment of extrajudicial torture is very difficult to justify in any civilized framework. This isn't even Jack Bauer torture, looking for information; it's for the sheer evil joy of getting back at someone.

Comment: Way to court controversy, mate! Welcome to SFF ;-)

Comment: You're forgetting that he spat in McGonagall's face. She was practically family to Harry - If someone did that to me, I'd do the same thing Harry did. Question is - would I do something like the Cruciatus Curse when I'm thinking normally? Of course not.

Comment: Yes, the way JKR treats those who use Unforgivable curses ... is twisted, just like in RL. Harry weasels out scot-free.

Comment: I'd argue it is not JKR, but the Ministry. It was not unintentional that "good" characters started using Unforgivable Curses in *Deathly Hallows*. Lupin even mentioned it  "at least Stun if you aren't willing to kill." They avoided Unforgivable Curses before because they were illegal, not because there's anything terrible about killing (or mind-controlling) someone who is trying to kill you. That said, Harry's acting against Amycus was an evil action (but *not* his whole character).

Comment: I'd postulate that there's no evidence that JKR thinks Harry's use of the Cruciatus Curse was justified, but that the way it played out kinda made sense. Was anyone really going to turn Harry in for using an Unforgivable Curse on a Death Eater? Was McGonagall going to tell him off for his choice of retaliatory curse, when Amycus had been torturing students all year? Naturally, using the Cruciatus Curse when Stunning spells and so forth are available is wrong. But Harry getting away with it makes sense. The scales don't always balance.

Comment: The ministry itself?

Comment: @rogerdpack Politicians are very good at making people believe they're good, but they're not(usually). Proof of this is at the end of the fourth book, the argument between Fudge and Dumbledore. If you're talking about Pius Thicknesse, it's unclear whether or not he was Imperiused. If I'm confusing you, what I'm trying to say that politicians are usually not 'good', they're just politicians.

Comment: Oh, but would it be evil to want to cause pain... TO HITLER?? Tum tum *tum*.

Comment: Of *course* it's evil to want to cause Bellatrix pain!

Comment: And of course, Harry shouldn't have punched Malfoy in the fifth year for insulting his mother. No situational necessity.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and I think an important one. There are lines that can be crossed and it's very important to point out when our heroes have crossed them, and not to excuse them.

Answer (score 56):

As Padfoot says,

> The world isn't split into good people and Death Eaters.

So 'joining Voldemort' would be a narrow definition of 'evil'.

Broadening that definition a bit, I could think of some:

- Petunia Dursley(I get it, she had problems, but if not opposing Vernon and Dudley when they harassed Harry *could* be considered as a form of evil; we have no reason to believe she didn't say anything when she could have).
- Grindelwald was another - he wasn't evil to begin with, just mischievous, but he turns evil in the end resulting in that duel and his lifelong incarceration in his own prison.
- Pettigrew, of course.
- Snape. Although we assume he was evil -> good, he actually was good -> evil -> good. He is shown to be good friends with Lily in childhood, but is plainly evil in adulthood as has been shown on multiple occasions.

Comment: I could think of more - Marietta, Draco, Petunia is a borderline case, even Sirius himself to a mild extent in the events of PoA. But these would be ones who were under pressure from external elements: desperation, circumstances etc. So I didn't include in the main list.

Comment: Oh wow, it never occurred to me that Snape initially went from good to evil. That's an incredibly good answer. I did consider Grindelwald, but as you say he wasn't really good or evil at the start, more just power hungry. And was Petunia ever good? I'm pretty sure in Snape's flashback she's shown as petty and jealous from childhood, it's unlikely that she would have gotten much better in order to just get so much worse in Harry's lifetime. Good answer though.

Comment: Petty and jealous yeah, but not *evil*.

Comment: Not sure I’d agree with Snape being ‘good’ even as a kid. Already at the time we first see him, he was rather a spiteful and vicious kid, damaged by his parents’ violent relationship and his own rather traumatic childhood. Lily is the only one he’s ‘good’ around, and he pretty much stays like that. It’s more a case of her bringing out the good in him than him changing from good to bad, as such.

Comment: Evil has a more striking definition, like Voldemort - he was evil, right from the start. He used to steal stuff, kill animals, and keep away from *everyone*. Even in school, *everything* he did was for personal gain. Snape was different - he was a troubled child, but not evil.

Comment: I'll disagree with Grindelwald. Paraphrasing here, but even Dumbledore says that he "pretended not to see what he really was" or something. He presented himself as an outgoing, well-intentioned radical, but even then he was a psychopath.

Comment: I dowvoted this, because you just present what you assume/see but are not even explaining it. I have doubts and don't share your views. And from the comments I see others do so aswell. so untill you not at least explaint it this action is appropiate I'd say.

Comment: @Zaibis What do you want me to explain? You need to have read the books. Assuming you know who the characters are, you shouldn't have any difficulty relating. You did read all the books, correct?

Comment: @cst1992 I didn't read them all but I'm aware of the plot over all of them. For example in my opinion it is contradicting declaring Petuinia becoming evil with your description of snape ever been good before turning evil. Grindelwald and Pettigrew I can let stay. But I can't see Petunia turned ever really evil. Just having a grudge on someone isn't beeing evil. And even if so, you can't say likeing her sister in the early childhood and later disliken contact to her is something about good and evil. same as taking harry up in their house or the relation at the end. Nothing I'd call clear evil.

Comment: @Zaibis That's why I used the word 'could'. People have differing views.

Comment: And in case you insist on this trait beeing something evil. Than you can't take the point for snape. Since then he was never really turned into evil but more so just from beeing bad (childhood) into something good. at what ever point. leaving away its doubtfull thats what op is asking for, even if I'm at somepoint wrong, you should describe then your view a bit more detailed in the answer.

Comment: I can't buy Snape not being evil at all. It's not just about Harry, but others too - remember poisoning Neville's toad? That *is* evil. Also, I should extend Petunia's point to both Petunia and Vernon, but I don't know Vernon's childhood. Dumbledore seconds my point in book six when he talks about the appalling damage to Dudley by their behavior. It's the *behavior* that's evil in their case, not the intent or feeling.

Comment: Well my first point about snape was, that he then never turned into evil but was it from the begining. and then jsut turned in some kind of good(opposite of OP). And well causing something with your behavior isn't evil if it isn't intentionally. And even then, would you call someone who is bad a raising his child consider evil, even if he is fighting against death eaters?

Answer (score 34):

[Note: this answer was written before the bit about Peter was edited into the question; I leave it up because I still think he is the best example.]

The most obvious answer I can think of is ***Peter Pettigrew***.

While he was never really what you might call a thoroughly *good* person, he was friends with James, Remus, and Sirius for many years while at Hogwarts, and his main character flaw there was apparently his insecurity. He was presumably always a bit of a coward, but he had strong friends and his cowardice didn’t seem to have made him a particularly bad person at this time.

His tendency to seek safety by siding with the ‘biggest boy in class’ and thus ending up in Voldemort’s camp was initially simply motivated by cowardice, but towards the end, during *Deathly Hallows* especially, he is no longer as much a coward as a truly bad person.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing already writing my update and didn't see this answer posted!

Comment: Also, I'd add to this, from the reader's perspective, we first meet him as this benign, slightly limp and useless, rat Scabbers, for which you might feel anything from mild contempt, through indifference, to mild fondness. But he was the pet of Ron, he bit Goyle, you feel really sorry for him in PoA, you think he's been gobbled by Crookshanks. And then he turns out to be this traitor and one of the central villains to the plot

Comment: Of course, it's debatable if any of the Marauders (sans maybe Lupin) could be considered "good" when they were that age.

Comment: I'd say he turned "evil" on or before the night he confronted Sirius.

Answer (score 12):

Aragog the spider could be considered. Was once Hagrid's pet / friend who was happy enough to answer some of Harry and friend's questions only to let his children (thousands of spiders) try to eat them.

Comment: Hm. 1) Had Aragog actually the authority to stop his offspring from trying? 2) Had he really *reason* to? This is moving into ethics, and human ethics don't really apply to giant spiders. Carnivores eat animals, and a human is an animal. Who's to say which kind of animal is "OK" to eat and which isn't? Humans eat whales, dogs, and monkeys, too. I don't see "evil" here.

Comment: I don't think arachnid ethics necessarily align with human ones.

Comment: Regardless of whether Aragog’s actions were evil, I’m not sure there’s much reason to believe that he had ever really changed — he may have been just as evil/amoral/whatever when he was smaller and still Hagrid’s pet, only less able to exercise it on a human scale.  I always saw Aragog as a bit of a cautionary lesson — showing that Hagrid’s trusting and generous nature, while a great thing most of the time, can also end up putting innocent people in danger, by being unable to acknowledge someone’s/something’s faults and the risks they pose.

Answer (score 11):

**Gellert Grindelwald**

He was maybe not the nicest person ever, but I don't know if he was truly evil when Dumbledore first befriended him.

Dumbledore was somewhat infatuated but I believe he would have known an evil person from a misguided one.

Grindelwald slowly turned more and more evil but as teenagers I would call both of them misguided but neither evil at that point.

Comment: He did get expelled from Durmstrang before meeting Dumbledore

Answer (score 7):

This could be a difficult sell: Voldemort. He may have had bad genes, but his backstory shows sponsorship by Dumbledore and it was Riddle's insecurities that turned him into an evil menace. Every issue can be traced back to fear of death and abandonment. You are not born an evil murderer. Circumstances and opportunity must line up to transport from mentally ill to evil. http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tom_Riddle

Comment: IIRC, it was maybe more a matter of increased ability / motivation to perform increasingly evil actions.  Riddle could still be evil even if he didn't murder anyone.

Answer (score 5):

In the alternate timeline created by Scorpius and Albus interfering with the second Triwizard Tournament task, **Cedric Diggory** ends up becoming a Death Eater.

> *SCORPIUS enters the library and starts desperately to look through books. He finds a history book.*
>
> SCORPIUS: How did Cedric become a Death Eater? What have I missed?
>
> *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, Act 3, Scene 4

Cedric is at least a decent guy originally, as we know from him helping Harry out with the "take a bath" tip to help Harry discover the nature of the second task.  So this probably counts as a good character becoming evil, at least in that particular alternate reality.

Comment: FYI, while it has been stated that Cursed Child is canon, that statement came from the marketing team behind it, not from Rowling. Apparently Rowling even debunked that statement.